# How can i upload images using send_keys() when element is hidden?

Tags: python, selenium

The following is HTML for uploading images.

```
<input _ngcontent-c23="" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" 
class="image-uploader" multiple="" pattern="'.jpg,.jpeg,.png'" type="file" 
hidden="">
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do mean by "element is hidden" ? Is the element not at all visible or there is another element that it is referring to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use normal send_keys with path.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("Path_of the_file")
```